# ASP.NET MVC - Return a List, grouped by a property in my Model

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I return a List, grouped by a property?

In my action, I return a view like so:

```
return View(context.Lines.Where(x=>x.EnquiryId == id).ToList());
```

This works fine, but what I need to do is group these Lines by a particular vehicle. In my Lines table, this has a column which stores the vehicle ID that a particular Line is linked too. For example, line 1 and 2, may have a vehicle ID of 1, where as line 3 and 4 may have a vehicle ID of 2.

Comment: what line do you want to get for a group ? line 1 or line 2 ? usually with a group by you specify some aggregate function

Comment: Basically I want to return a list of all Lines, grouped by a vehicle, this is iterated through on my view. At the moment with my current code, it just iterates through each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to group or just order? Because if your result is a list of items, you'll just want to order them properly.

```
var result = context.Lines
    .Where(x => x.EnquiryId == id)
    .OrderBy(x => x.VehicleId)
    .ToList();
```

GroupBy returns a list of lists:

```
var result = context.Lines
    .Where(x => x.EnquiryId == id)
    .GroupBy(x => x.VehicleId);
```